# Does anyone know examples on valuation field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory

Does anyone know examples on valuation field? Also, I need some a good reference on that subject.

Comment: There are some examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)#Examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a book, try [Local Fields](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9781139171885) by J. W. S. Cassels and [Basic Algebra II](http://store.doverpublications.com/048647187x.html) by Nathan Jacobson.

See also these [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410FULL.pdf) by Pete L. Clark.